# This seemingly harmless code does not produce any output

Tags: c++

Question - Find a pythagorean triplet (a,b,c) such that a+b+c =1000.

This is the code, I wrote it for Project Euler #9. I know it is a very ineffecient code, but the logic 'should' have done the job. The code produces no output at all. I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long a,b,c;
    for(a=1; a<335; a++)
    {
        for(b=1;b<335; b++)
        {
            c = 1000-a-b;
            if(a*a + b*b  - c*c == 0)
            {
                cout<<a*b*c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `c = 1000-a-b;` look suspect.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: Can you name *one* pair of numbers `a`, `b` for which `a`, `b`, `1000 - a - b` is a Pythagorean triple?

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=9
I haven't looked up the solution, but there will be one. 

@Nathan I am doing this as the question demands so.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: Edited the question, Added the behaviour..

Comment: For what value(s) of a, b, and c do you expect to get output?

Comment: I have found the error, I have posted it as an answer. The triplets satisfying the solution is (200,375,425). Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the polynomial in the `if` condition is never equal to zero given that `1 <= a < 335` and `1 <= b < 335`.

```
a**2 + b**2 - (1000 - a - b)**2 == -2*a*b + 2000*a + 2000*b - 1000000
```

Comment: Why can't a\*\*2 + b\*\*2 - c\*\*2 never be 0?  If you have 3,4,5 then the result is 0.

Comment: @NathanOliver: 3 + 4 + 5 != 1000

Comment: @PaulR I get that but `a**2 + b**2 - c**2` can equal 0.  2 other answers confirm that.

Comment: I guess the answer is right if you added to it is says *for the range you are checking*.  As it it reads like this will never work.

Comment: @NathanOliver, but it doesn't given the constraints in the OP's code. Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. The code mistakenly has put the condition that all the 3 numbers of the triple must be smaller than 334. Here is the edited code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long a,b,c;
    for(a=1; a<998; a++)
    {
        for(b=1;b<998; b++)
        {
            c = 1000-a-b;
            if(a*a + b*b  - c*c == 0)
            {
                cout<<a*b*c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Your code still has at least one bug, since c can now be negative.

Comment: And since `a` and `b` are interchangeable, you can `for(b=1;b<a; b++)` (we know `b!=a` because sqrt(2) is not rational).

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen to small values as your loop-termination condition (the initial problem description doesn't specify in what range `a`, `b`, or `c` may lie).

If you increase them, say, to 1000, you will see the output of:

> 31875000

And if you modify your code to print individual `a`, `b`, or `c` values, you will get:

> 200 375 425

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/bOd8FX).

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer stated, the polynomial in your if condition never equals zero, because you did not give your test numbers a large enough range. Try something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long a,b,c;
    for(a=1; a<1000; a++)
    {
        for(b=1;b<1000; b++)
        {
            c = 1000-a-b;
            if(c < 0)
              continue;
            if(a*a + b*b  - c*c == 0)
            {
                cout<<a*b*c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your code you assumed that the `a`, `b`, and `c` values shouldn't be more than a third of 1000, but they are! This just means that you have to test all possible cases, because each number `a`, `b`, and `c` could technically be any number between 0 and 1000. However, this could result in negative values for `c`, and assuming your natural numbers have to be positive, you should skip any time your `c` becomes negative, hence the `if(c < 0) continue;` bit. (it skips to the next iteration of the inner-most loop)

Answer (score -2):

Do you looking for this:

```
#include <cmath>
const double EulerConstant = std::exp(1.0);
```

Or euler's method: look here: [eulers method](http://math60082.blogspot.com.tr/2013/02/c-coding-eulers-method.html).

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question - it's a problem from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net).